The argument type 'Future<dynamic>? Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback?'
there's an error while trying to update onSelectNotification to onDidReceiveNotificationResponse
  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSettings,
      onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: _onSelectNotification);

Future<dynamic>? _onSelectNotification(String? payloadNotification) {
  if (kDebugMode) {
    print("Notification selected.");
  }

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    if (payloadNotification != null && payloadNotification != "") {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print(payloadNotification);
      }

      // parse notification content like this.
      // PushRequest.Message message =
      // PushRequest.Message.fromJson(jsonDecode(payloadNotification));
      //
    }
  });
  return null;
}

it just throws this error when renamed it to new one "The argument type 'Future? Function(String?)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback?'."

onDidReceiveNotificationResponse needs to be of type DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback, which your _onSelectNotification isn't.
DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback is defined as:
typedef DidReceiveNotificationResponseCallback = void Function(
    NotificationResponse details);

So you need to change
Future<dynamic>? _onSelectNotification(String? payloadNotification) {

to
void _onSelectNotification(NotificationResponse response) {

it might be possible to make it a Future instead of a void but I'm not entirely sure about that.
To get the payload from it you can do response.payload
